# Can find a way to get this query

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I can't figure out the way out of my problem, Is there a better way to do this?.

It's supposed to check if the data exist and if it does, update the last table quantity with the sum of it and the new quantity. And if it doesn't exist create the table. But I can't get it to work, the table just updates.(there's no data in the database)

Here is my php:

```
$SESSID = session_id(); 
//(session_id,bid,date_added,qty)
$q = "SELECT quantity FROM cart WHERE session_id = '$SESSID' AND item_id = '$itemID'"; 
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$check = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
if($check=='' && $r==FALSE){
    $addtocart = "INSERT INTO cart (item_id, quantity, date_added, session_id) VALUES ('$itemID', '$qty', '$datetime', '$SESSID')";
    echo 'create';
}else{
    $total = $r + $qty;
    echo $total;
    $addtocart = "UPDATE cart SET quantity = '$total' WHERE session_id = '$SESSID' AND item_id = '$itemID'";
    echo 'update';
}
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $addtocart);
//go to showcart 
/*header("location:../tienda?cart");*/
exit; 
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns `NULL` if there are no more rows to fetch. Also, using prepared statements is probably the easiest way to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: there is more code than just that, wich I created to stop the sql injections, I just added the usefull code. Thanks for the ´mysqli_fetch_assoc´ explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just a single query:

```
INSERT INTO `cart` (`item_id`, `quantity`, `datetime`, `session_id`)
VALUES ('$itemID', '$qty', '$datetime', '$SESSID')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `qty`=`qty`+values(`qty`)
```

This assumes that your database table was built properly, and has a `UNIQUE KEY` on `` (`item_id`,`session_id`) ``.

Comment: the key doesn't need to be defined in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cart` (`item_id`, `quantity`, `datetime`, `session_id`)
VALUES ('$itemID', '$qty', '$datetime', '$SESSID')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `qty`=`qty`+values(`qty`)
```

assuming that item_id is set to `unique`

Comment: I have a doubt. The qty can't be replace with quantity rigth? so I have to call the value before I call the query?

Comment: sry, but the IGNORE didn't work for me, good answer though, I couldn't have imagine an IGNORE.